# Large Deviation Principle for the Empirical Path Law. Brownian Particles.

Tags: probability, brownian-motion, large-deviation-theory, empirical-processes

I'm looking for a Large Deviation Principle for the Empirical Path Law. Someone must have done this right? That is, for $i\in \mathbb{N}$, $t\in[0,T]$, let $X^i(t)\in \mathbb{R}^d$ be (the position of) iid Brownian Particles, with say $X^i(0)=x_0$. Define the empirical path law

$$  L^n:=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \delta_{X^i(\cdot)} $$

where $\delta_X$ is the dirac mass at $X$ measure on an appropriate path space $C([0,T];\mathbb{R}^d$). Is there a result for a LDP for (the measure associated to) $L^n$, if so where is it?!

Comment: Is this a random measure, or the measure associated to a particular path?

Comment: Sorry, I mean an LDP for the measure associated to $L^n$ (since yes its random)